Neo4j Browser expand only specific nodes
In Neo4j Browser, there is a visual option to expand a node in a graph so its other relationships that are not yet visible become visible (for example if you double click on the node).
My problem is, that I don't want all the other relationships to be shown. I want to filter out the nodes with certain labels. This can be easily done for the initial graph:
MATCH (n1)-[r]->(n2) 
WHERE not n1:unwanted_label
RETURN r, n1, n2

but when I explore the graph further, also nodes with label unwanted_label will be opening up.
Every answer will be appreciated.
I have already tried changing the size of nodes with label unwanted_label to 0px with help of :style, but the relationships (arrows) are still shown.

If you are using the Neo4j Desktop or Neo4j Enterprise Edition, you can use Neo4j Bloom to visualize only the node labels you are interested in (along with their associated relationships), via a customized Perspective.
Note that the UI of Bloom is very different from Neo4j Browser, so you will have to spend a little time to learn it.

Thanks a lot for you reply! Will give it a try.

This is not possible to do. Delete nodes one by one.

Actually I found a way, but not very elegant, by setting the relationship color to the background color.
